# If I have two routes in flask pointing towards the same url, how does flask decide what functions to run?

Tags: python, flask

I have a simple flask app where I take an image file path from an input page and then switches over to an output page with the image being displayed. My app works properly and manages to access my saved files and displays them on the new page, but I realized I have two routes that point towards the same place. My code is shown below:

```
@app.route('/')
def main_page():
    return render_template('input_receiver.html')

@app.route('/', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def get_input():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = request.form['nm']
        return redirect(url_for('success', name=user))
```

These two functions point towards my initial localhost:5000 page, the first function renders an html file with a text field input and a button. In order to connect to the actual flask script, it includes the following line in the form tag:

`<form action = "http://localhost:5000" method = "post">`

('nm' is the text field input on the initial HTML page)

The second function takes in the user input of the local image file path and redirects them to an HTML file after they press a button which displays the picture they entered. This is done through the below function.

```
@app.route('/<name>')
def success(name):
    return render_template('popup.html', picture_path = "/static/" + name)
```

Both routes point towards the initial localhost:5000 page, so how does flask handle execution? If this is considered as a bad way to create this sort of functionality, what is the better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put both `GET` and `POST` in the same method under same `route`.

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def get_input():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = request.form['nm']
        return redirect(url_for('success', name=user))
    return render_template('input_receiver.html')
```

You have already given the methods as `GET` and `POST` for the route `/`  - method `get_input()`, so you can completely remove the other method - `main_page`.

Both your `GET` and `POST` request can be handled by this one method.